# Duda con while en java

Tags: java, while

tengo un problemita con un codigo while, y es que no se como realizar la segunda parte de mi codigo.

Este es el codigo que estoy realizando:

1. Si el usuario ingresa dinero mayor a 500, muestre por pantalla el mensaje NOMBRE_PERSONA eres mi angel. Y finalice el ciclo con un break.
2. De lo contrario, muestre por pantalla NOMBRE_PERSONA me decepcionas. Y el ciclo se volverá a ejecutar.

De momento tengo la primera parte que seria esta

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Mesada{

public static void main(String args[]){

     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
     int dinero = teclado.nextInt();
     while(dinero>500){
         System.out.println(nombre+" eres mi angel");
         break;
```

Ojala me puedan explicar como hacer la segunda parte, gracias.

Comment: Ya que te piden que abandones el ciclo con un `break;`, lo suyo sería hacer `while(true)` y dentro del ciclo asignar `int dinero = teclado.nextInt();` y ahí ya compruebas si es mayor o menor de 500, así saldrá del ciclo solo si entras al `if` donde está el `break;` y si no entra, seguirá ejecutándose.

Answer (score -1):

agrega una variable boolean en false (boolean meta=false)
Cambia la condición de el while a (meta!=ture)
Dentro de el while agrega un if-else, condicionando el if

```
if(dinero>500) {
    System.out.println(nombre+" eres mi angel");
    meta=true;
   }else{
    sout(nombre+", me decepcionas");
    }
```

Suerte.

Comment: Esto no cumple con lo solicitado en la pregunta: *Si el usuario ingresa dinero mayor a 500, muestre por pantalla el mensaje NOMBRE_PERSONA eres mi angel. Y finalice el ciclo con un break.*.